# Gradient of a function in different coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be an open subset endowed with a triple orthogonal coordinate system ($x^1,x^2,x^3$) and $f\in \mathcal{C}^\infty (U)$ be a smooth function. The vector field $\nabla f$ which is called a gradient of a function $f$ can be defined in coordinates $x^1,x^2,x^3$ by means of the $1$-form 
$$(\omega_X)_p(v_p)=\langle X_p,v_p\rangle$$
as follows
$$\omega_{\nabla f}=df.$$
I want to find the gradient of a function $f$ in coordinates $x^1,x^2,x^3$ and then in particular cases: Cartesian, cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

Any ideas?